# How to configure SVN access list for directory/repository?

Tags: svn, windows-server-2008, apache2

I have next SVN repositories structure running Apache 2.2 under Windows Server 2008:

http://example.com/svn/ is targeted to `e:\svn` (root)

http://example.com/svn/dir/ is targeted to `e:\svn\dir` (some directory with a number of repositories)

http://example.com/svn/dir/repo/ is targeted to `e:\svn\dir\repo` (a repository itself)

How to access list so group `@foo` had `rw` access to `repo`?

I have next access list:

```
[groups]
@foo = user1, user2

[/]
* = r

[dir/repo:/]
@foo = rw
```

The last string doesn't work in any combination I tried

Apache conf is next:

```
<Location /svn>
    SVNParentPath "E:\SVN"

    DAV svn
    SVNListParentPath on
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Subversion repositories"
    Require valid-user

    AuthUserFile svn-auth.txt
    AuthzSVNAccessFile svn-acl.txt
</Location>

<Location /svn/dir/>
    SVNParentPath "E:\SVN\Dir"

    DAV svn
    SVNListParentPath on
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Subversion repositories"
    Require valid-user

    AuthUserFile svn-auth.txt
    AuthzSVNAccessFile svn-acl.txt
</Location>

<Location /svn/dir2/>
    SVNParentPath "E:\SVN\Dir2"

    DAV svn
    SVNListParentPath on
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Subversion repositories"
    Require valid-user

    AuthUserFile svn-auth.txt
    AuthzSVNAccessFile svn-acl.txt
</Location>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've configured this as

```
<Location /dir>
    SVNParentPath e:\svn\dir
    AuthzSVNAccessFile e:\accesslist.txt
```

then you probably just want

```
[repo:/]
```

because the access list will be relative to e:\svn\dir. If not, could you post the <Location> snippet for e:\svn\dir? Thanks!

Comment: PS: `[repo:/]` doesn't work. Maybe I have to create a separated access list file for each directory under root? (I have a number of `<Location>` with different `SVNParentPath`)

Comment: Thanks - that all looks OK to me :-/ Sorry, one thing I didn't spot before: I think it's just "foo = user1, user2" not "@foo =" in the groups definition, or at least we only use the @ for the directory permission lines. I still think it's just [repo:/] without the dir in the svn-acl.txt that's referenced by your &lt;Location /svn/dir&gt; though.

Didn't see your PS before I posted that - I guess not then. If that doesn't work I'm out of ideas, sorry :-/

Comment: I set separated access list file to Dir (svn-access-dir.txt) where set rules relatively and it works, i.e. `[repo:/]`. But it's very interesting - is it possible to have one file for all subdirs?